# How to return an error message on socket timeout with Spring-Integration

Tags: java, spring, sockets, spring-integration

I'm using `Spring (Integration)` to offer a socket tcp connection. I'm having a specific timeout for this socket.

When the timeout is exceeded, I not only like to shut down the connection (which already works), but also return custom error message (or not closing the connection, but just return the error message). Is that possible?

```
@Bean
public TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean tcpFactory(Converter converter) {
    TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean factory = new TcpConnectionFactoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setType("server");
    factory.setPort("8080");
    factory.setSingleUse(true);
    factory.setSoTimeout(10000); //10s; how to return error message?
    return factory;
}
```

---

Update:

```
@Bean
public ApplicationListener<TcpConnectionEvent> tcpErrorListener() {
    TcpConnectionEventListeningMessageProducer producer = new TcpConnectionEventListeningMessageProducer();
    producer.setEventTypes(new Class[] {TcpConnectionCloseEvent.class});
    producer.setOutputChannel(tcpErrorChannel()); //what to do here?
    return producer;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you mind to show StackTrace when soTimeout is exhausted ? I'll try to find the code from there, where you can wedge

Comment: Actually I don't get any stacktrace shown on timeout (at least on the server side. I don't have the client side).

Comment: Where do you want to return the error message ? If simply to an error log, then log4j and/or slf4j are made for that.

Comment: I'd prefer to return the error message over the socket, instead of just cutting down the open connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually any closed connection emits `TcpConnectionCloseEvent` and you can get deal with it using:

```
<int-event:inbound-channel-adapter channel="connectionClosedChannel" 
      event-types="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpConnectionCloseEvent"/>
```

Having that you not only close connection, but can do any desired logic with that `event-flow`.

**UPDATE**

To use it from JavaConfig:

```
@Bean
public SmartApplicationListener tcpErrorListener() {
    ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer producer = new ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer();
    producer.setEventTypes(TcpConnectionCloseEvent.class);
    producer.setOutputChannel(tcpErrorChannel());
    return producer;
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel tcpErrorChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

Comment: That looks promising. Is `int-event` already annotation supported?

Comment: Added JavaConfig sample

Comment: Could you maybe try to provide a complete example? This seems to be a very complicated setup, and I cannot find any examples on in. Also, `ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer` seems to be removed from the current v4 of spring integration. Instead I can only find a `TcpConnectionEventListeningMessageProducer`. I updated my current code above, but anyhow I still don't know how to provide the `MessageChannel` by `tcpErrorChannel()`.

Comment: Add `tcpErrorChannel()` declareation. You should add `spring-integration-event` dependency to your project.

Comment: Yes I know I can create one of the `MessageChannel` classes myself. But back to the root of the problem: how can I then set a custom error message as returned payload, instead of closing the tcp connection?

Comment: I have `spring-integration-event` v 4.0.1.RELEASE as dependency, there's no `ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer`

Comment: ???: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/v4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-integration-event/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/event/inbound/ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer.java

Comment: The `closing connection` isn't overridable functionality. Where are going to return error message to, if socket is closed by soTimeout ?

Comment: So sorry, a mvn clean solved at least the dependency. The class is found now.

Comment: I thought I'd by able to "catch" the `soTimeout` somehow, and then (instead of closing the connection) return a custom error message instead to the sender (as the timeout is defined from the serverside, not from the client).

Comment: Timeout is defined by server-side but it is applied for `serverSocket.accept()` and exactly its `connection` is closed, because that `socket` isn't valid already. The `serverSocket` isn't closed anyway. I guess you try to send message to the connected client. But in this case your sender should just `try...catch` its exception on send.

Comment: Yes ok, I did not mean to shutdown the serverSocket. I only want to prevent the connection closed to the client on timeout, but instead return a custom error message. Maybe a bit more detailed insight why I want to achieve this: the client is a legacy application with a fixed and non-changeable timeout. The client only has two outcomes: 1.) display the `String` message that is recieved, 2) fail completely. Therefore, I must define the timeout on the server shorter than the client, and return a custom error message instead of closing the active socket of the client, to limit client side errors

Comment: Got it. So, your issue is around this code: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-ip/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/ip/tcp/connection/TcpNetConnection.java#L192. So, you can handle `TcpConnectionExceptionEvent` on `read from that client socket` and send an error to it from that `event flow`

Comment: No not exactly. The client has a fixed timeout, and cannot recieve any messages from the socket the exceeds that timeout. So, my server socket timeout must be lower, and send a custom string error message back *before* the clientside timeout is exceeded, as in this case no further communication is possible. There's no use of detecting read-from-client-errors as in this case the client is already stuck. Is it maybe possible to `veto` a `TcpConnectionCloseEvent`? I could then use your code above, veto the closing and just return a custom message somehow?

Answer (score 1):

The requirement is a little unusual - what will the client do when it gets the custom error message?

There is currently no easy way to intercept the timeout; you could do it, but you'd have to subclass the connection factory and the connection objects it creates, and override the `handleReadException()` method.

It would likely be much easier to just handle the sockets directly in your own component and send messages to your flow using a [Messaging Gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway). Or, simply make your component a subclass of `MessagingGatewaySupport`.

Alternatively you could use something in your downstream flow (and don't set a timeout). When a message is received, schedule a task to send the error message in 10 seconds. When the next message arrives, cancel the scheduled task and schedule a new one.

Comment: The client will just display the custom error message, and the user of the client will react accordingly. The legacy tool will not handle connection timeout properly and cause unpredicable errors. Thus I have to prevent closing the connection. So, maybe a custom scheduler is the only chance here...